# Sum of entries of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, noncommutative-algebra

For a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, it is clear that the sum of all the entries of $A$ can be expressed as
$$\vec{1}^{T} A \vec{1} = \sum \limits_{i,j} A_{i,j}$$

Now suppose $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are symmetric matrices. Then by the above expression, it is clear that the sum of the entries of the product $AB$ is the same as that of $BA$, even though the two are distinct as matrices.
So 
$$\vec{1}^{T} (AB+BA) \vec{1}=2\vec{1}^{T} AB \vec{1}$$

Do we have any such expression for higher degrees? That is, suppose we form the sum of all possible permutations of a product of $n$ repetitions of $A$ and $m$ repetitions of $B$, and let $Symm(A^nB^m)$ denote this sum. For example, when $n=3$ and $m=2$, the expression has $\binom{5}{2}$ terms as follows
$$Symm(A^3B^2)=A^3B^2 + A^2BAB + A^2B^2A+ABA^2B+ABABA+AB^2A^2+BA^3B+BA^2BA +BABA^2+B^2A^3$$

Can we say anything useful about
$$\vec{1}^{T} Symm(A^nB^m) \vec{1}$$
in terms of $A,B$?

---

This came up while working on a larger problem, so I've skipped the context here as of now. I apologize if the question is a bit vague and open-ended, and will update it promptly based on any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you consider  that the sum of entries of $AB$ is equal to sum of entries of $BA$ (probably it's true)? For me it is not obvious from your formula, but maybe an explanation is simple..

Comment: @Widawensen It easily follows from$A$ and $B$ being symmetric matrices. $1(AB)1=1(AB)^T1=1(B^TA^T)1=1(BA)1$. The problem is that this method doesn't extend to a product of more than two symmetric matrices, except in trivial cases.

Comment: Thank you for explanation.   Very interesting property..

Comment: I interpreted that the end of aim in your question how  calculate simply the function. Is it true?

Comment: @Hayabusananji Precise calculation seems overambitious. I'd be satisfied with bounds on the value in terms of, say, the spectra of A and B. Or even general approaches to obtain bounds in such problems.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be the square matrix whose each element is $1$.
(Is there canonical notation for this?)
This is a symmetric matrix.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$

The sum of elements of $A$ is $s(A)=\tr(AX)$.
For symmetric $A$ and $B$ the sum of elements in the product is
$$
s(AB)=\tr(ABX)=\tr((ABX)^T)=\tr(X^TB^TA^T)=\tr(XBA)=\tr(BAX)=s(BA).
$$
This you already knew, but I just wanted to give a new point of view to this fact.
Similarly, it's easy to check that $s(A^T)=s(A)$ for any matrix $A$.

Given the commutativity properties of the trace — and more importantly, lack thereof — I don't think there will be a nice identity to allow you to treat arbitrary permutations nicely.
Matrices don't commute with $X$ in general.
It's hard to prove non-existence of useful things to say, but perhaps the trace helps clarify your thoughts.

For example, in your example you can take $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=X$.
Then all terms with $A^2$ vanish, and $Symm(A^3B^2)=ABABA=A$.
This $A$ is not symmetric; the point is just to emphasize that the order of matrices can have big effects (also on trace: typically $\tr(ABC)\neq\tr(BAC)$), and this is true with or without symmetry.
In general, the order of the matrices will have a significant effect on the sum of elements of the product, but it's hard to say more than that.
If you have a more specific question, I can try to think of a specific answer.

Comment: Very interesting. I like your expression $s(A)=Tr(AJ)$ (by the way, the common notation for the all 1s matrix is $J$, as far as I have seen). I agree that it is hopeless to expect a simple  expression in general, but I have more specific matrices in mind. So lets see if your approach helps. Will keep you posted if it helps. Thanks for this new way of looking at $s(A)$.

Comment: But that apart, is $Symm(A^mB^n)$ studied anywhere? I simply made up the notation here. It seems like a natural object when dealing with matrix products, sort of like the elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: @BharatRam Not that I know of. But the notation is confusing: $A^mB^n$ is a matrix, but your $Symm(A^mB^n)$ is not a function of this matrix; you need to know $A$, $B$, $m$ and $n$ separately. Symmetrized tensor products are more common in my experience, but it's an entirely different beast.

Comment: True. Maybe I should have used $Symm(A,m;B,n)$ or such. I just came up with it ad hoc. Anyway, the context I had in mind is $A$ being an adjacency matrix of a graph, $B$ being a diagonal matrix of the degrees. I am trying to squeeze out some bounds on $Symm(A,m;B,n)$ in terms of, say, the spectrum of $A$.

Comment: The matrix $A$ you have given is not symmetric, so you can't use it in a counter example, can you ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom It was a simple attempt to demonstrate what might happen because of non-commutativity. There was no exact claim, so I can't give a counter example. :) But the point stands: The order of matrices does have an effect on the trace. Maybe I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: So maybe you just want to say that generally $\operatorname{tr}(ABC)$ and $\operatorname{tr}(CBA)$ are not equal ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom I thought that was clear enough, but I added it explicitly now.